# AWS EKS, I encountered a tolerations error in all ArgoCD pods

Tags: amazon-eks, argocd

I used the following command to install the Argo CD in the EKS fargate cluster.

```sh
$ VERSION=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/latest" | grep '"tag_name"' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/')
$ sudo curl --silent --location -o /usr/local/bin/argocd https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/$VERSION/argocd-linux-amd64 
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/argocd
```

```sh
$ kubectl create namespace argocd 
$ kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

And I look up the namespace resources, the state of the pad is pinging as follows.

```sh
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/argocd-application-controller-0       0/1     Pending   0          3m47s
pod/argocd-dex-server-65bf5f4fc7-dh4ql    0/1     Pending   0          3m47s
pod/argocd-redis-d486999b7-rn9g8          0/1     Pending   0          3m47s
pod/argocd-repo-server-8465d84869-jwj47   0/1     Pending   0          3m47s
pod/argocd-server-87b47d787-29mcp         0/1     Pending   0          3m47s

NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/argocd-dex-server       ClusterIP   172.20.30.228    <none>        5556/TCP,5557/TCP,5558/TCP   3m47s
service/argocd-metrics          ClusterIP   172.20.229.100   <none>        8082/TCP                     3m47s
service/argocd-redis            ClusterIP   172.20.240.101   <none>        6379/TCP                     3m47s
service/argocd-repo-server      ClusterIP   172.20.133.210   <none>        8081/TCP,8084/TCP            3m47s
service/argocd-server           ClusterIP   172.20.39.79     <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP               3m47s
service/argocd-server-metrics   ClusterIP   172.20.32.2      <none>        8083/TCP                     3m47s

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/argocd-dex-server    0/1     1            0           3m47s
deployment.apps/argocd-redis         0/1     1            0           3m47s
deployment.apps/argocd-repo-server   0/1     1            0           3m47s
deployment.apps/argocd-server        0/1     1            0           3m47s

NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/argocd-dex-server-65bf5f4fc7    1         1         0       3m47s
replicaset.apps/argocd-redis-d486999b7          1         1         0       3m47s
replicaset.apps/argocd-repo-server-8465d84869   1         1         0       3m47s
replicaset.apps/argocd-server-87b47d787         1         1         0       3m47s

NAME                                             READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/argocd-application-controller   0/1     3m47s
```

And I look up one of the pods, the following errors appear.

```sh
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  70s (x4 over 4m2s)  default-scheduler  0/5 nodes are available: 5 node(s) had taint {eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type: fargate}, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

All pads have the same error.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you use eksctl to create your EKS cluster?

Comment: @gohm'c I created eks cluster with cdk.

Comment: @gohm'c I created a fargate profile and put {app: 'appName' and tier: 'backend'} in the label for deployment.

Comment: Can you run the command `aws eks describe-fargate-profile --profile <named profile> --cluster-name <your EKS cluster name> --fargate-profile-name <your fargate profile name>`, remove your account info and post the output to the question?

Comment: {
    "fargateProfile": {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "subnets": [// subnet list],
        "tags": {},
        "clusterName": "dev-cluster",
        "fargateProfileArn": "arn:aws:eks:ap-northeast-2:<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:fargateprofile/dev-cluster/dev-cluster-profile/xxxxx",
        "selectors": [ { "namespace": "dev-cluster" } ],
        "fargateProfileName": "dev-cluster-profile",
        "podExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/dev-cluster-devclustertfargat-xxxxx",
        "createdAt": 1644567740.993
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Fargate was created to run deployment to "dev-cluster" namespace:

```
{
  "fargateProfile": {
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    ...
    "selectors": [{
        "namespace": "dev-cluster"
    }]
  ...
```

But you deploy argocd to another namespace:

> $ kubectl create namespace argocd
>
> $ kubectl apply -n argocd ...

Try apply your argocd to "dev-cluster" namespace instead.

Comment: It works!!!!!!!. Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Only pod in the namespace selected by your Fargate profile will run on Fargate infrastructure. This is necessary because not all pod is eligible to run on Fargate, example pod that requires EBS cannot run on Fargate. You can fine tune your profile by adding label which means; only pod that runs in the selected namespace **and** with the label will run on Fargate infrastructure, so in the same namespace you can have pod running on node group and Fargate simultaneously.